# Change the defaultValue of A custom control property

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I created a number of custom controls but still struggling mastering the interface.
For uniformity besides creating custom proerties I also want to change some base properties of the custom control I tried following code

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnControlAdded(e As ControlEventArgs)
    Me.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    Me.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    MyBase.OnControlAdded(e)
End Sub
```

That however does not work when I drop the custom control on a form, I suppose the solution lies with adding the  attribute and overriding the property.

I found an answer to this for C# but did not succeed to understand/translate it for vb.net

Comment: You aren't adding any controls to a ComboBox, so your code doesn't fire.  Put that code in the constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech, I am not looking for initiating data when the form/controls initiates but to change the default value of the control (in our case they default to "none" per default) to other default values at design time.

Comment: Since you want to set inherited properties, your choices are limited - the actual default is already set in the base control. The simplest is to set it to what you want in the constructor; in cases where the control implements `ISupportInitialize` you can act in `EndInit`.  This assumes it is a custom control and not a user control

Comment: Show that c# solution you have.

Comment: @LarsTech, it's on this site as "Changing the DefaultValue of a property on an inherited .net control".

Comment: @LarsTech, I understand what they suggest: overriding the property adding <DefaultValue(True)> and referring to the baseclass.property+Constructor  ... but ... those specific properties are not overridable ...

Answer (score 0):

Since those properties are not overridable, try using the [Shadows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785.aspx) modifier instead:

```
Public Class MyComboBox
  Inherits ComboBox

  Public Sub New()
    Me.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    Me.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
  End Sub

  <DefaultValue(AutoCompleteMode.Suggest)> _
  Public Shadows Property AutoCompleteMode As AutoCompleteMode
    Get
      Return MyBase.AutoCompleteMode
    End Get
    Set(value As AutoCompleteMode)
      MyBase.AutoCompleteMode = value
    End Set
  End Property

  <DefaultValue(AutoCompleteSource.ListItems)> _
  Public Shadows Property AutoCompleteSource As AutoCompleteSource
    Get
      Return MyBase.AutoCompleteSource
    End Get
    Set(value As AutoCompleteSource)
      MyBase.AutoCompleteSource = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Please note though, the DefaultValue attribute probably doesn't do what you think it does: it doesn't actually set a default value of that property.  All it is used for is to tell the PropertyGrid what the default value for the property is, and if it matches it, it won't make it **bold** in the PropertyGrid view and it won't serialize the value in the designer file.